# how do get values when i click on particular country dynamically like this is showing of india

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

How to get value from `json`?

this is first api

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.population.io/1.0/countries/?format=json"];  
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
NSString *encodedUrlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrlAsString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"DATA: %@",data);

            if (!error) {
                // Success
                if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                    NSError *jsonError;
                    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

                    if (jsonError) {
                        // Error Parsing JSON
                    } else {
                        // Success Parsing JSON
                        // Log NSDictionary response:
                        arr = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"countries"];
                        NSLog(@"%@",arr);
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    }
                }  else {
                    //Web server is returning an error
                }
            } else {
                // Fail
                NSLog(@"error : %@", error.description);
            }
        }] resume];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{     
    return arr.count;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {   
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    ViewController1 *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    vc.str1 = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

this is second one

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.population.io/1.0/wp-rank/1952-03-11/male/India/on/2001-05-11/?format=json"];

NSString *encodedString = [urlAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",response);

            NSLog(@"DATA: %@",data);

            if (!error) {
                // Success
                if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                    NSError *jsonError;

                    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

                    if (jsonError) {
                        // Error Parsing JSON

                    } else {
                        // Success Parsing JSON
                        // Log NSDictionary response:

                       // _str2 = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"dob"];

                       /// NSLog(@"%@",_str2);

                        NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);
                    }
               }
          }
     }
```

when i click particular country i should get data from that country

Comment: your question is not clrar

Comment: iam using one api to go to this one when i click particular country there it should pick same country from this api too

Comment: @swativerma From where you are picking country ?

Comment: NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.population.io/1.0/countries/?format=json"];

Comment: @swativerma where do you display this country or from  where do you want to select particular country.?

Comment: @swativerma - show the code of when we click on the partcilur country

Comment: i displayed on tableview then clicking paticular country i have to get details of that country in other view controller from this api

Comment: @swativerma Then show that code to use add code for that controllers and didSelect

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    
    ViewController1 *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    
    vc.str1 = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: @swativerma Don't add code in comment, Edit your question and add code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use that `str1` property that you are setting in `didSelect` method to make your `URL`, so replace the `India` with `str1`'s value.

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.population.io/1.0/wp-rank/1952-03-11/male/%@/on/2001-05-11/?format=json", self.str1];
```

**Note:** You need to give proper name to your property, so better if you changed `str1` to `selectedCountry` or something else.

Comment: @swativerma Welcome mate :)